# Squid allow both authenticated and ip based logins

Tags: squid

I have a proxy server which allows users to connect and authenticates them via user/pass but some of them are complaining about this method since not many of the available proxy software support that method so I wish to config my squid in such way that it allows members to connect via user/pass or based on their pc ip but I'm not sure if that could work. Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've had an end-user authenticated proxy in place for years and yet to encounter an important situation that did not have a reasonable work-around.  Point being, they are rare.

In Windows, the `proxycfg` utility is often a big help.  Work-arounds are often specific to software and depending on the type you may find more help on Superuser.

You could use ACLs but authentication usually makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah but some of the clients are using bots like scrapebox and such which use proxies but lack the support for proxy authentication so, is it possible to have these 2 entirely different ACL types working hand in hand?

Comment: I'd think so but I've never done it.  Have you considered dedicating a "server" to this role, which has direct access to the Internet?